# Noise Filtering in 3D Kinect Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, kinect, noise-reduction

I want to perform Noise filtering on a image taken by Kinect2 in Matlab R2015b. I have a cardboard with objects drawn on it. Now when I picture it with Kinect some points(Noise) appear in picture which were not present in real 2D cardboard line.

I tried to calculate a plane function and every point which is beyond this plane is noise. But results are not be good as Noise is not being right filtered. What technique must i follow?

[image: Cardboard]

Comment: may be you should add your noisy depth image

Comment: Include the noisy image, what filtering you have tried, and why you think it hasn't worked

Comment: I assume that you have a depth image!? Is this cardboard always planar?If yes, are you only interested in the plane or any background stuff as well?